# Functions that satisfy $f(n) = \sum_{d|n, d\neq n} f(d)$ and $f(1) = 1$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $f: N \rightarrow N$ satisfies $$f(n) = \sum_{d|n, d\neq n} f(d)$$ and $f(1) = 1$

Compute $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f(2021^k)}{2021^k}$$

The function is curious. I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function, but it doesn't quite help me..

Comment: Indeed, **Moebius inversion technique** could provide an answer, but I don't see clearly how in this case.

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A074206](https://oeis.org/A074206) "Kalmár's [Kalmar's] problem: number of ordered factorizations of n." which has more information.

Comment: @Somos Indeed in connexion with https://oeis.org/A067824. Kudos ! How did you find it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Please refer to my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step is to identify the sequence defined by
$$ f(n) = \sum_{d|n,d\ne n}f(d) \quad \text{ and } \quad f(1)=1 \tag{1}. $$
The first terms are $\,1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3,\dots\,$ and
an OEIS search finds it to be [A074206](https://oeis.org/A074206)
"Kalmár's [Kalmar's] problem: number of ordered factorizations of n."
Notice that $\,f(n)\,$ **only** depends on the form of the factorization of
$\,n\,$ into primes. Thus, $\,f(p^n)=2^{n-1}\,$ if $\,p\,$ is any prime.
The next step would be to find $\,U(n,m):=f(p^n q^m)\,$ where $\,p,q\,$ are two
distinct primes. This is given by [A059576](https://oeis.org/A059576)
"Summatory Pascal triangle T(n,k) (0 <= k <= n) read by rows." More
precisely,
$$ T(n,k)=U(n-k,k) \tag{2} $$
where $\,T\,$ is the entries of the infinite $2$D array $\,U\,$
read by anti-diagonals.
The OEIS entry gives the two-variable generating function
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty U(n,m)\, z^n w^m = \frac{(1-z) (1-w)}{(1 - 2 w - 2 z + 2 z w)}. \tag{3} $$

Now we want to find the infinite sum
$$ S := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f(2021^k)}{2021^k}. \tag{4} $$ Notice
that $\, N := 2021 = 43\cdot 47 \,$ is the product of two primes. Thus,
$$ S = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{U(k,k)}{N^k} = F(1/N) \quad
\text{ where } \quad F(x) := \sum_{k=0}^\infty U(k,k)\,x^k. \tag{5} $$
Similar to the case of
[OEIS sequence A008288](https://oeis.org/A008288) "Square array of
Delannoy numbers D(i,j) (i >= 0, j >= 0) read by antidiagonals."
and its main diagonal
[OEIS sequence A001850](https://oeis.org/A001850) "Central Delannoy
numbers" we find that
$\,U(k,k)\,$ is [OEIS sequence A052141](https://oeis.org/A052141)
and its generating function $\,y=F(x)\,$ satisfies
$$ 0 = (4x^2-12x+1)(y^2-y)+(x^2-3x). \tag{6} $$ The solution is
$$ y = \frac{ 1-12x+4x^2+\sqrt{1-12x+4x^2}}{2-24x+8x^2}. \tag{7} $$
Substituting $\,x = 1/N\,$ gives $\,S\approx 1.00149080995973599729777313. $

Comment: [+1] About ordered factorizations, a valuable reference is https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrderedFactorization.html

Comment: Can you elobrate why $T(n,k) = U(n-k,k)$?  I don't quite follow the OEIS page..

Comment: So I checked OEIS for $U(k,k)$ and I found http://oeis.org/A052141   But I don't quite understand why paths from (0,0) to (1,1) is 3 (shouldn't it be 2?) and to (2,2) is 26.  Also how exactly do we translate from 2-variable generating functions to one in A052141 becuase the generating function in A052141 can directly give us the result.

Comment: @MattFrank Thanks for mentioning A052141! Don't worry about the path enumeration. They probably use steps $(0,1),(0,1),(1,1)$. The derivation of the g.f. of $U(k,k)$ from $U(n,m)$ is not easy so I skipped it.

Comment: Thanks. If you can elaborate how you got $ 0 = (4x^2-12x+1)(y^2-y)+(x^2-3x). \tag{6} $ that would be great too!